# how to get the no of pages from .doc file in php, the following code works for .docx not .doc

Tags: php

** this code working .docx format document   **
** but my need  .doc format document count pages number in php **

```
function CountPagesDocx($filename)
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if($zip->open($filename) === true)
    {  
        if(($index = $zip->locateName('docProps/app.xml')) !== false)
        {
            $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
            $zip->close();

            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
            return $xml->Pages;
        }
        $zip->close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561719/find-out-page-numbers-of-pdf-docx-doc-ppt-pptx-files-with-php

Comment: Thanks for your Link. But your provided link is not solving my .doc file issue..

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to get page count of .doc document.

Step 1: Make sure `php_com_dotnet.dll` on your php.ini file. If you can not find that, you have to add that first(you don't want to download any .dll, just add following line), After you add this extension **restart Apache server**.

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

Step 2: Run this answer, [PHP MS Word files page count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230276/php-ms-word-files-page-count). When you add the `$filename`, add that this way,

```
$filename = "C:\\xampp\htdocs\project\myfile.doc";
```

Step 3: Before you running the script. Make sure that word document is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I have done many implementations on docx pdf and xlsx using java.
NOt sure about PHP
But i will help you with one the description which will be help full

Try this way:

```
**For docx** 
you can find the total page numbers in  docProps/app.xml
inside:
<Pages>5</Pages>

**For doc** 
Open file in text mode and find this key
PAGE   \* MERGEFORMAT 
next to it you will find DC 4 NAK
so now it is understood that 4 is the total number of pages in doc.
```

Thank you ..

Comment: There are many builtin ways to achieve this but this for simple.