# How to count total number of pages only for .doc not .docx file in php

Tags: php, file, doc

I want to count the number of pages of .doc file. I have used `ZipArchive()` but its works only for `.docx` and also used linux command

`"vSummary sample.doc | grep -oP '(?<=of Pages = )[ A-Za-z0-9]*'`

but its also not works. Can anyone give mw to solution for get page count for .doc file in PHP.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if($zip->open($file) === true) {
    if(($index = $zip->locateName('docProps/app.xml')) !== false)
    {
        $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
        $zip->close();

        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
        print_r($xml);
        $pageCount= $xml->Pages;
    }
 
    $zip->close();
}
```

And also used of linux command :

`wvSummary sample.doc | grep -oP '(?<=of Pages = )[ A-Za-z0-9]*'`

But not working

Comment: _I have used_ Please post your codes. You cant expect the community to write the entire function for you.

Comment: Hello @user3251758, you might want to take a look into: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @endeavour with zip archive function :  $zip = new ZipArchive();
  if($zip->open($file) === true) {
    // echo "vvvvv";
    if(($index = $zip->locateName('docProps/app.xml')) !== false)
        {
            $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
            $zip->close();

            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
            print_r($xml);
             $pageCount= $xml->Pages;
        }
       echo "<pre>";
        print_r($xml);
        $zip->close();
}

Comment: Please edit your question with proper syntax. The questions use markdown to format a piece of text. When you post there should be a help section that tells you how to format common parts

Comment: Refer to this question for an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40826396/how-to-get-the-no-of-pages-from-doc-file-in-php-the-following-code-works-for